# Checkbox disable and enable while loading and unloading

Tags: asp.net

I am having a asp checkbox with checkedchanged event.
Whenever user checks or unchecks page refreshes.
During its refresh, I need to disable the checkbox and after completing refresh, checkbox should get enable.

Comment: is it ajax post back ??..because if you are going to refersh i.e. postback page checkbox will remain disable ..

Comment: Disable it using jquery/js on click/change event. Later it'll automatically enabled after page refresh.

Comment: @DSA I think your sol will suit for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is not so good... But one way is:

```
protected void your_checkedchanged_method(object sender, EventArgs e){
//some logic
checkboxID.Enabled = false;
}
```

and your page_load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
//your works
//checkBoxID.Enabled = true;
}
```

It makes your checkbox disabled on checked changed, and on Page load it enable your checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

you use disable the checkbox at client side, so it will not allow you click two times. codes may like below:

```js
function CheckBoxClick(e) {
            e.disabled = true;
        }
```

```html
<asp:CheckBox Text="test" runat="server" ID="testCheck" AutoPostBack="True"  onclick="CheckBoxClick(this)"
            oncheckedchanged="test_CheckedChanged"  />
```